# Android and using dependencies. Is it ok? Like using someone else's build implementation of something in your code.

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

So like the title says, is it ok to use someone elses implementation of something? Like for instance i used this well known PagerSlidingTabStrip in my code.

https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip

So let's say i used this in my gradle in my dependencies and the app i was making was to go to the google play store. Is this legal? Or do i need the permission from the creator. If you could please also give me some guidelines to follow for these type of things.

Sorry for the dumb question but I'd rather ask then not.

Thank you.

Comment: People generally put code on github so others can use it. So it's fine to use them since that's why the owners put it on git hub the first place

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you're using a library from github, check the license at the bottom of the page.

PagerSlidingTabStrip is licensed under the Apache 2.0 license, which you can read about [here](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0). In short you're fine to 'redistribute' the library along with your own work.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the clarification. I know it wasn't a great question to ask, but I just wanted to be sure. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

almost most of libraries over github and maven central are open source. so you can use it in your code.

but you should check license type.

Comment: Open source doesn't mean that you can use it in your project as you want. You have to check always the licence